# How to inject Injector?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Situation: i need lazy dependency instantiation in some `FooClass`, so i pass `Injector` to class as a constructor parameter.

```java
private final Injector m_injector;
    
public FooClass(@Named("FooInjector") Injector injector) {
    m_injector = injector;
}
```

But guice doesn't permit to bind core classes (injectors, modules and etc). What is the solution?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should not be using the `Injector` directly. Rather pass in the `Provider<FooClass>` instead. Also, you should be injecting the provider in the places where you use `FooClass`.

```
private final Provider<FooClass> provider;

@Inject
public ClassWhereFooIsUsed(Provider<FooClass> provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}

.... somewhere else
FooClass f = provider.get(); // This is lazy
```

Comment: Thx! I'll try it for lazy initialization. But is there really no way to inject Injector?

Comment: You can get the injector with `@Inject Injector injector`, can be on the constructor / field / method.

Comment: Did you try this? How configure module? Guice restricts binding to core classes: "Binding to core guice framework type is not allowed: Injector."

Comment: `@Inject Injector injector` code injects the same `Injector` that used to create instance. So, i suppose, that there is no way to inject other `Injector`.

Comment: @AlexM: Have a look at `childInjectors` if you really need. In general they should not be needed and you should only use a single injector. There are exceptions but they are rare.

Comment: Why do you need multiple Injectors? I really can't imagine.

Comment: @Alex M - There's no need to configure an Injector in order for the Injector itself to bounded. By default, every injector know how to inject itself. http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html

Answer (score 15):

As others have already answered, you can simply use `@Inject Injector` because Guice defines the binding itself.

Normally you only need one `Injector` in your app, and a static variable is an even easier way to store and access a singleton than injecting it.  In our web app, we use [stripes-guicer](http://code.google.com/p/stripes-guicer/) and get the `Injector` from its static method `GuiceInjectorFactory.getInjector()` when we need it (in our Hibernate interceptor, for example).

I'm a little baffled by the advice that "you shouldn't use Injector directly."  How else would I get an instance injected except by calling `injector.getInstance()` or `injector.injectMembers()`?  There is no way.  Yes, you can define Provider methods, but they will never be called unless somewhere, something uses an Injector.  Yes, there are modules that use the `Injector` for you like the [ServletModule](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule); you have to create the `Injector` yourself, but you can leave it to the `ServletModule` after that.

So in some circumstances, you can avoid using the `Injector` directly, but that doesn't mean you "shouldn't" use it.  If you're using Guice alone without any optional modules, then you "should" be using an `Injector` all over the place because there's no other way to trigger injection.  (I think developers who spend all day writing code inside frameworks sometimes forget that some people actually instantiate their own objects.)

Comment: I am not convinced you have understood the rationale behind Guice. It explictly aims to avoid using static fields and state, and you should only very rarely make a direct reference to the Injector itself. You get instances injected by declaring dependencies with @Inject, rather than calling `getInstance()` on  the injector.

Comment: My only point (which I made rather verbosely) is that you have to start somewhere; it's a chicken-and-egg problem.  You can't *only* decorate methods with @Inject and expect anything to happen.  Something, somewhere, must call injector.getInstance() or injector.injectMembers() to start it all off.

Comment: What about in a reflection context? Where you do not know the class you want from the context at compile-time?

Comment: It’s not so much “You shouldn’t use `Injector` directly” as much as “You shouldn’t *inject* `Injector`”.
Guice provides a lot of checks on Module creation, none of which work if the stuff *inside* the module end up injecting an `Injector` themselves.
The initially manually created `Injector` from `Guice.createInjector(...myModules)` is perfectly fine to use.

Answer (score 8):

As @gpampara said, `Provider<T>` should be used for lazy/optional initialization. Also, as I said in my answer to your other question, you should be avoiding references to the `Injector` in your code in almost all cases.

That said, in a class that is created by Guice, the `Injector` that is creating the object can be injected just by declaring a dependency on `Injector`. The `Injector` is automatically available for injection without you declaring any binding for it.

If you do inject the `Injector`, you should think about WHY you want to do that. Why don't you just declare dependencies on the actual interfaces/classes the class depends on? It's just as easy to add a new dependency to the constructor as it is to retrieve an instance of some dependency through the `Injector` elsewhere in your code, and it makes the code far more understandable as well.

Comment: Re: "WHY you want to do that" - For example I want to create dynamic proxies on the fly after bootstrap. my question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252268/best-practice-for-creating-dynamic-proxies-with-guice

Comment: Another use case: I'm using a third-party library to unmarshal domain objects from storage/network and would like to allow them to require services from the DI graph.

Comment: Re: "WHY you want to do that". I'm using Quartz, and in the job I want to call another service --> I must create my own JobFactory. To instance an job I need an Injector. That's the point.

Answer (score 3):

The arguments that you *probably* shouldn't be injecting an instance of `Injector` are quite valid, but as with any rule there are exceptions.

I have a factory class that takes in class references for which it needs to provide an instance.  The instances aren't necessarily known (really, they are, but there are a lot and there might be more) so I can't make Providers for all of them.

```
public class ThingFactory {
    private Injector injector;

    @Inject
    ThingFactory(Injector injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
    }

    public <T> T getInstance(Class<T> aClass) {
        return injector.getInstance(aClass);
    }
}
```

The real class in my app is extending and overriding another class—that's why this class is basically a passthrough to Guice.

Comment: One example is JobFactory when using Quartz. Tks