# Proper structure for dependency injection (using Guice)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

I would like some suggestions and feedback on the best way to structure dependency injection for a system with the structure described below.  I'm using Guice and thus would prefer solutions centered around it's annotation-based declarations, not XML-heavy Spring-style configuration.

Consider a set of similar objects, `Ball, Box, and Tube`, each dependent on a `Logger`, supplied via the constructor.  (This might not be important, but all four classes happen to be singletons --- of the application, not Gang-of-Four, variety.)

A `ToyChest` class is responsible for creating and managing the three shape objects.  `ToyChest` itself is not dependent on `Logger`, aside from creating the shape objects which are.

The `ToyChest` class is instantiated as an application singleton in a `Main` class.

I'm confused about the best way to construct the shapes in `ToyChest`.  I either (1) need access to a Guice `Injector` instance already attached to a `Module` binding `Logger` to an implementation or (2) need to create a new `Injector` attached to the right `Module`.

(1) is accomplished by adding an `@Inject Injector injector`field to `ToyChest`, but this feels weird because `ToyChest` doesn't actually have any direct dependencies --- only those of the children it instantiates.

For (2), I'm not sure how to pass in the appropriate `Module`.

Am I on the right track?  Is there a better way to structure this?

The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176216/how-to-inject-injector) mention passing in a `Provider` instead of using the Injector directly, but I'm not sure how that is supposed to work.

EDIT:

Perhaps a more simple question is: when using Guice, where is the proper place to construct the shapes objects?  `ToyChest` will do some configuration with them, but I suppose they could be constructed elsewhere.  `ToyChest` (as the container managing them),  and not `Main`, just seems to me like the appropriate place to construct them.

Comment: Ball, Box and Tube are all application singletons but they are created by ToyChest?  Can you clarify why this needs to be the case?  Could they instead be given to ToyChest when it was constructed?

Comment: 1) ToyChest decides which are created.  2) They could be passed in to ToyChest via the constructor, but they are aren't needed anywhere else.  So that would (in my opinion) needlessly complicate the constructor.  There's also a turtles-all-the-down problem.  What creates them to pass to ToyChest?  Perhaps passing them in via the constructor is the right way and I'm just not seeing the larger structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper way is to have guice construct your dependencies. That is create and configure.

In your situation you should have an injector constructed in the `Main`. From the injector you get `ToyChest`. When you obtain `ToyChest` through the injector its managed by guice and you can depend on it to supply all dependencies properly configured.

In your case you can inject `Provider<Ball>`, `Provider<Box>`, etc. in `ToyChest` and when needed just retrieve instance from the provider. `ToyChest` is not responsible for constructing the instance, just to use it. You can also check [MapBinder](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings) if you have a plugin architecture.

So far everything is managed by guice, so the shapes can have their logger injected without the using class knowing about it.

If you have some runtime parameters that you want to pass to the newly created shape instances, you can use [AssistedInject](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject).

Just a hint: you are not required to use constructor injection, you can have injection on field or setter, which simplifies the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, this supports the conclusion I've come to after asking the question and suggests some other options to consider.  ToyChest needs to be DI-aware, either by accepting the shapes via the constructor/setters or or by accepting a factory/provider/mapbinder from which the get the shapes.  I think my hang-up is in inverting that much of my control!