# how to create an object from a different scope

Tags: java, dependency-injection, scope, guice

I have an object in Guice with scope singleton. In method `f()` I want to create a new object but let Guice do the injection.
I think it is not a good practice to pass the injector around.
So how can I get a new "Guicy" instance of object?

Comment: I just came to write the same question, hope you get a good answer

Comment: Perhaps you can use a provider http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above, probably provider is the way to do it. it is also mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176216/how-to-inject-injector).